# How can I grab data series from xml or tcx file

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xpath, beautifulsoup

I want to treat data from .tcx file (xml form) between specific tags with Python.
File format is like as follows.

```
 <Track>
      <Trackpoint>
        <Time>2015-08-29T22:04:39.000Z</Time>
        <Position>
          <LatitudeDegrees>37.198049426078796</LatitudeDegrees>
          <LongitudeDegrees>127.07204628735781</LongitudeDegrees>
        </Position>
        <AltitudeMeters>34.79999923706055</AltitudeMeters>
        <DistanceMeters>7.309999942779541</DistanceMeters>
        <HeartRateBpm>
          <Value>102</Value>
        </HeartRateBpm>
        <Cadence>76</Cadence>
        <Extensions>
          <TPX xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2">
            <Watts>112</Watts>
          </TPX>
        </Extensions>
      </Trackpoint>
....Lots of <Trackpoint> ... </Trackpoint>
</Track>
```

Eventually, I'll make Data table with columns of 'Lattitude, Altitude, ... Watts'.
First I tried to make a list from taged data (like Watts ... /Watts) with BeautifulSoup, xpath etc.
But I'm a newbie to deal with these tools.
How can I grab data between tags in xml file with Python?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `lxml` module, along with `XPath`. `lxml` is good for parsing XML/HTML, traversing element trees and returning element text/attributes. You can select particular elements, sets of elements or attributes of elements using `XPath`. Using your example data:

```
content = '''
<Track>
      <Trackpoint>
        <Time>2015-08-29T22:04:39.000Z</Time>
        <Position>
          <LatitudeDegrees>37.198049426078796</LatitudeDegrees>
          <LongitudeDegrees>127.07204628735781</LongitudeDegrees>
        </Position>
        <AltitudeMeters>34.79999923706055</AltitudeMeters>
        <DistanceMeters>7.309999942779541</DistanceMeters>
        <HeartRateBpm>
          <Value>102</Value>
        </HeartRateBpm>
        <Cadence>76</Cadence>
        <Extensions>
          <TPX xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2">
            <Watts>112</Watts>
          </TPX>
        </Extensions>
      </Trackpoint>
....Lots of <Trackpoint> ... </Trackpoint>
</Track>
'''

from lxml import etree

tree = etree.XML(content)
time = tree.xpath('Trackpoint/Time/text()')

print(time)
```

**Output**

```
['2015-08-29T22:04:39.000Z']
```

Comment: Thanks for simple solution. I got the other data except the Watts. Maybe the TPX "xmlns=..." tag causes problem. Can you test about it?

Answer (score 2):

You can even use `lxml` module to convert XML to CSV (for later import into a dataframe, spreadsheet, or database table) using an iterated Python list across various XPaths.

Notice the very last `Watts` node is a special, longer XPath due escaping the special namespace, `xlmns` not registered in sample XML.

```
import os, csv
import lxml.etree as ET

# SET DIRECTORY
cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# LOAD XML FILE
xmlfile = 'trackXML.xml'
dom = ET.parse(os.path.join(cd, xmlfile))

# DEFINING COLUMNS
columns = ['latitude', 'longitude', 'altitude', 'distance', 'watts']

# OPEN CSV FILE
with open(os.path.join(cd,'trackData.csv'), 'w') as m:
    writer = csv.writer(m)    
    writer.writerow(columns)

    nodexpath = dom.xpath('//Trackpoint')

    dataline = []   # FOR ONE-ROW CSV APPENDS
    datalines = []  # FOR FINAL OUTPUT 
    for j in range(1,len(nodexpath)+1):        
        dataline = []

        # LOCATE PATH OF EACH NODE VALUE
        latitudexpath = dom.xpath('//Trackpoint[{0}]/Position/LatitudeDegrees/text()'.format(j))
        dataline.append('') if latitudexpath == [] else dataline.append(latitudexpath[0])

        longitudexpath = dom.xpath('//Trackpoint[{0}]/Position/LongitudeDegrees/text()'.format(j))
        dataline.append('') if longitudexpath == [] else dataline.append(longitudexpath[0])

        altitudexpath = dom.xpath('//Trackpoint[{0}]/AltitudeMeters/text()'.format(j))
        dataline.append('') if altitudexpath == [] else dataline.append(altitudexpath[0])

        distancexpath = dom.xpath('//Trackpoint[{0}]/DistanceMeters/text()'.format(j))
        dataline.append('') if distancexpath == [] else dataline.append(distancexpath[0])

        wattsxpath = dom.xpath("//Trackpoint[{0}]/*[name()='Extensions']/*[name()='TPX']/*[name()='Watts']/text()".format(j))
        dataline.append('') if wattsxpath == [] else dataline.append(wattsxpath[0])

        datalines.append(dataline)
        writer.writerow(dataline)

print(datalines)
```

In addition to CSV file, below is the datalines list output of selected columns:

```
[['37.198049426078796', '127.07204628735781', '34.79999923706055', '7.309999942779541', '112']]
```

Comment: Your solution is that I want! But it does not work. The error message is like this.   File "xml2obj.py", line 15, in <module>
    with open(os.path.join(cd,'trackData.csv'), 'w', newline='') as m:
TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: This is a Python 3 solution. You may be using Python 2.7 that does not take `newline` as an argument in `open()` function. Simply remove it. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The Python program https://github.com/cast42/vpower/blob/master/vpower.py iterates over the TCX file specified at the command line and add a power field for all measurements of the cycling activity.
It uses the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library for speed and because it deals with namespaces. In previous versions of this program I used xml.etree.ElementTree but ran into problems with the namespaces.